# adjust_for_ambient_noise gives timeout error in silence

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am using following code for simple speech recognition. This code detects spoken phrase if there is silence and `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)` line is commented.
If there is background noise then have to enable `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)`

The problem is, if there is silence and `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)` is enabled then I get "`WaitTimeoutError: listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start`" from `r.listen`

Please suggest what combinations of `r.listen` and `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise` and parameters should be used, so that if someone speaks "tommy" then the code breaks out of loop.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone() #device_index=1)
sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()

text = ""
while text.lower() != "tommy":
    with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=3, phrase_time_limit=3)
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a while loop with a try and except statement to accomplish this. The try and except stops the error from occuring if nothing is spoken, and sets the output to an output other than "Tommy". Because the output is not equal to "Tommy", the listening will run over and over again until the phrase "Tommy" is heard.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone() #device_index=1)
sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()

text = ""
while text.lower() != "tommy":
    with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        except:
            text = ""
        print(text)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).